# How to architect and implement models with similar state and behavior in django?

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class

I have the following models:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)


class Department(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)



class LocationInvite(models.Model):
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    def send(self):
        location = self.location.member
        email = self.location.member.email
        send_populated_email(location, email)
        self.sent = True
```

I need to allow departments to have invites as well.

I am thinking of changing LocationInvite to Invite and making it an abstract base class.  I will then create 2 concrete implementations LocationInvite and DepartmentInvite.  I will move the location foreign key to the LocationInvite class.

How then will I refactor the send method of Invite to accommodate extracting the email address of either the Location or the Department, depending on the concrete implementation?

My question is, is using an abstract base class a good architecture move and how would I implement it given the constraints of the send method?

These records will be in the millions, so that is why I did not mention using **generic foreign keys**.  Unless this is not a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an abstract base class and let both invite types extend from it.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the attribute access into a separate property, and override in each model.

```
class Invite(...):
  def send(...):
    self._group....
     ...
   ...

class LocationInvite(Invite):
   ...
  @property _group(self):
    return self.location

class DepartmentInvite(Invite):
   ...
  @property _group(self):
    return self.department
```

Comment: what is the group?  Also what does the implementation look like in the invite abstract class?

Comment: The "group" is the location or department. There is no property implementation in the abstract class.

Comment: what does the . . .  look like after self._group in the Invite?  I'm just unclear from this example.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like what you already have, except the `self.location` part.

Comment: ok, so it looks like:  def send(self):self._group.member ?  Then I can access that attribute from each implementation with @property _group(self): ?

Comment: shouldn't the self._group in invite be outside the send method?